# Verifying integer input in a union in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to verify that what a user inputs in to one section of a union is actually an integer.  I have been trying to use the isdigit function (see below) but I am having no success.  All I need to do is make sure the user enters ONLY numbers for the date, but I am having a lot of trouble with it.

My code:

```
#define STRSIZE 30
#define PROFSIZE 30
#define NBRASSI 2
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0


struct assignment
{
    char name[STRSIZE];
    char prof[PROFSIZE];
    int duedate;
    float value;

};
```

.
.
.

```
struct assignment populate_structure(struct assignment assi[], int assi_nbr)
{
    int count;
    int date_check = FALSE;

for (count = 0; count < assi_nbr; count++)
{
    flushall();
    printf("Enter Assignment #%d name (max %d chars):\n", count + 1,
            STRSIZE);
    gets(assi[count].name);

    while (date_check == FALSE)
    {
        printf("Enter due date for Assignment #%d (YYYYMMDD):\n", 
            count + 1);
        scanf("%d", &assi[count].duedate);
        if (isdigit(assi[count].duedate))
        {
            date_check = TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid");
            date_check = FALSE;
        }
    }

    printf("Enter %% of final grade for Assignment #%d:\n", count + 1);
    scanf("%f", &assi[count].value);
    flushall();
    printf("Enter Professor's name for Assignment #%d (max %d chars):\n",
        count + 1, PROFSIZE);
    gets(assi[count].prof);
    printf("\n\n");
}
return assi[count];
```

}

It gives me no errors in Visual Studio, but when I run the program I get an Abort error whenever ANY value is input for assi[].duedate

If I remove if (isdigit(assi[count].duedate)), the program runs fine (so long as they only input an integer for duedate).  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which `union` are you talking about? There is none in the code. But your `scanf`: test its return value, then you can be sure. It should be `1`.

Comment: `isdigit` checks a single character. So the code would need to take the `duedate` as a string. Then you could use a `for` loop to check that each character in the string is a digit.

Comment: If you are entering an 8-digit sequence  for `YYYYMMDD` you would do better entering a string, ensure it is 8 characters long, and process each of those chars, bearing in mind they characters, not numerals. Having an `int` with that date value is not very useful to the library date functions anyway.

Comment: How is `populate_structure()` called? What is being passed? And how is the latter defined and initialised?

Comment: Did you read the documentation to `isdigit()` & Friends?

Answer (score 0):

As the commenters already noted: `isdigit()` is for single characters only. Also: the way you use `scanf()` already assures the result to be a number.

But you should read a string instead, it is easier to test. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
  int c;
  int position = 0;
  int res;
  char date[9] = {'\0'};
  char input[20] = {'\0'};

  puts("try if date is in the format \"YYYYMMDD\"");
  res = scanf("%19s",input);
  if(res != 1){
    fprintf(stderr,"input was a mess, aborting\n");
    goto __FAILURE;
  }
  c = input[position];
  while(c != '\0'){
    switch(position){
       case 0:
          if( c == '2' || c == '1' ){
            date[position] = (char) c;
          } else {
            goto __FAILURE;
          }
          break;
       case 1:
          if( c == '9' || c == '0' ){
            // check valid digit by looking back here
            // (not implemented)
            date[position] = (char) c;
          } else {
            goto __FAILURE;
          }
          break;
       case 2:
          if( isdigit(c) ){
            date[position] = (char) c;
          } else {
            goto __FAILURE;
          }
          break;
       case 3:
          if( isdigit(c) ){
            date[position] = (char) c;
          } else {
            goto __FAILURE;
          }
          break;
       case 4: // month
          if( c == '0' || c == '1' ){
            date[position] = (char) c;
          } else {
            goto __FAILURE;
          }
          break;
       case 5: // month
          if( isdigit(c) ){
            // check valid digit by looking back here
            // (not implemented)
            date[position] = (char) c;
          } else {
            goto __FAILURE;
          }
          break;
       case 6: // day
          if( c == '0' || c == '1' || c == '2' || c == '3'){
            date[position] = (char) c;
          } else {
            goto __FAILURE;
          }
          break;
       case 7: // day
          if( isdigit(c)){
            // check valid digit by looking back here
            // (not implemented)
            date[position] = (char) c;
          } else {
            goto __FAILURE;
          }
          break;
       default:
          break;
    }
    c = input[++position];
  }

  printf("Date was correct and is %s\n",date);
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
__FAILURE:
  printf("Date was wrong at position %d with character %c or just too short/long\n",position,c);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Fill out the rest (check if date is valid and in the correct range). You could also part the date into individual year/month/day sections instead of putting the string into another string and convert them into numbers via `atoi` ( you can use `atoi` `because you already made sure to have a valid number) or by converting manually inside the switch without extra variables and functions. Checking ranges arithmetically is simpler than comparing strings/characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my offering - any invalid entry calls `exit(1)` though a better error handler would be preferred. The data is entered as a string, and then extracted and validated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct {
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
} mydate_t;

int main(void){
    int i;
    mydate_t dat = {0};
    int dayspermon[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    char str[12];
    printf("Enter a date (YYYYMMDD): ");
    fflush(stdout);
    if(fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin) == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }
    for(i=0; i<8; i++) {
        if(!isdigit(str[i])) {
            exit(1);                 // also fails when the string is too short
        }
    }

    // extract
    for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
        dat.year = dat.year * 10 + str[i] - '0';
    }
    for(i=4; i<6; i++) {
        dat.month = dat.month * 10 + str[i] - '0';
    }
    for(i=6; i<8; i++) {
        dat.day = dat.day * 10 + str[i] - '0';
    }

    // validate
    if(dat.year < 2000 || dat.year > 3000)    // arbitrary range
        exit(1);
    if(dat.year % 4 == 0 && (dat.year % 100 != 0 || dat.year % 400 == 0)) {
        dayspermon[1]++;                      // leap year adjustment
    }
    if(dat.month < 1 || dat.month > 12)
        exit(1);
    if(dat.day < 1 || dat.day > dayspermon[dat.month - 1])
        exit(1);

    printf("Date: %04d %02d %02d\n", dat.year, dat.month, dat.day);
}
```